# Getting exception message

Tags: python

What is the difference in getting exception message via `str(e)` and `e.message` in

```
except Exception as e:
    ...
```

block of code

Comment: Aside from the fact that `e.message` itself may raise an `AttributeError`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get exception message in Python properly](/q/33239308/90527)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `e` doesn't have a `message` attribute, `e.message` will raise an `AttributeError`. `str(e)`, on the other hand, won't do anything worse than return an empty string.